# Convert string with special characters to hex - C#

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, hex, special-characters

Hi I'm trying to transform a string containing special characters like `û` and `…`.

In my research and tests I almost succeeded using the following function:

```
public static string ToHex(this string input)
{
    char[] values = input.ToCharArray();
    string hex = "0x";
    string add = "";
    foreach (char c in values)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
        add = String.Format("{0:X}", value).Length == 1 ? 
            "0" + String.Format("{0:X}", value) + "00" 
            : String.Format("{0:X}", value) + "00";
        hex += add;
    }

    return hex;
}
```

If I try to decode `´o¸sçPQ^ûË\u000f±d` it does it correctly and turns it into this `0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005E00FB00CB000F00B1006400`,

instead when I try to decode `´o¸sçPQ](ÂF\u0012…a` it fails and turns it into `0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002800C200460012002026006100` instead of this
 `0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002800C2004600120026206100`.

Making a minimum of debug I saw that the string is transformed from 
`´o¸sçPQ](ÂF\u0012…a` to `´o¸sçPQ](ÂF.a`, I wouldn't want that to be the problem but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

```
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002800C2004600120026206100                  ´o¸sçPQ](ÂF…a           CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002800C200460012002026006100                ´o¸sçPQ](ÂF.a       MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003D00CB0042000C00A50061006000AD004500BB00  ´o¸sçPQ]=ËB¥a`­E»         CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003D00CB0042000C00A50061006000AD004500BB00  ´o¸sçPQ]=ËB¥a`­E»         MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00D30042001900B7006E006100              ´o¸sçPQ]/ÓB·na          CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00D30042001900B7006E006100              ´o¸sçPQ]/ÓB·na      MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005F001A20BC006B0021003500DD00                  ´o¸sçPQ_‚¼k!5Ý          CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005F00201A00BC006B0021003500DD00                ´o¸sçPQ_'¼k!5Ý          MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00EE006B00290014204E004100              ´o¸sçPQ]/îk)—NA         CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00EE006B0029002014004E004100            ´o¸sçPQ]/îk)-NA         MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003800E600690036001C204C004F00              ´o¸sçPQ]8æi6“LO         CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003800E60069003600201C004C004F00            ´o¸sçPQ]8æi6"LO         MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00F3006200390014204E004700C602          ´o¸sçPQ]/ób9—NGˆ        CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00F300620039002014004E0047002C600       ´o¸sçPQ]/ób9-NG^        MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003B00EE007200330078014100                  ´o¸sçPQ];îr3ŸA          CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003B00EE0072003300178004100                 ´o¸sçPQ];îr3YA          MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003000F20064003E009D004B00                  ´o¸sçPQ]0òd>K           CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D003000F20064003E009D004B00                  ´o¸sçPQ]0òd>?K          MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00E60075003E00                          ´o¸sçPQ]/æu>            CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00E60075003E00                          ´o¸sçPQ]/æu>            MY OUTPUT

0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00EE006A003000DC024500                  ´o¸sçPQ]/îj0˜E          CORRECT
0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002F00EE006A0030002DC004500                 ´o¸sçPQ]/îj0~E          MY OUTPUT
```

I thank you in advance for every reply or comment,

greetings.

Comment: A Char is a UTF-16 code unit. Each should be 4 hex digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and different integer and string encodings.

```
char cc = '…';
Console.WriteLine(cc);
// 2026  <-- note, hex value differs from byte representation shown below
Console.WriteLine(((int)cc).ToString("x"));
// 26200000
Console.WriteLine(BytesToHex(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)cc)));
// 2620
Console.WriteLine(BytesToHex(Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16").GetBytes(new[] { cc })));
```

You should not treat chars as integers. There are plenty of different ways to encode strings, .net internally uses UTF-16. And all encodings works with bytes, not with integers. Explicit conversion chars to integer can lead to unexpected results, like yours. Why don't you get encoding you need and work with bytes via `Encoding.GetBytes`?

```
void Main()
{
    // output you expect 0xB4006F00B8007300E700500051005D002800C2004600120026206100
    Console.WriteLine(BytesToHex(Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16").GetBytes("´o¸sçPQ](ÂF\u0012…a")));
}

public static string BytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    // whatever way to convert bytes to hex
    return "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Comment: this is an answer, thank you for your time and the explanation provided!

Comment: `Why don't you get encoding you need and work with bytes via Encoding.GetBytes?` Because i didn't know! I had done my research but I had not encountered anything that could hint at the problems that emerged. Some of my results were right and others not, I didn't think there was such a problem.